# DataLoader CLI Could not find main class FindJavaRunner

Tags: data-loader, commandline, dataloader-batch

Okay, so currently, I'm trying to create an AutoIt script that would RunWait a command to run a Data Loader upsert. However, I've been running into several issues with running the process.bat batch file from a different directory. My Data Loader files installed to my User's AppData folder, and the directory I'm working in is my User's Documents folder.

I originally would get an error where the command line wouldn't be able to find dataloader-42.0.0-java-home.exe which I fixed by adding the bin directory it's in to the Path Environment Variable. However, now the error I'm getting is "Error: Could not find or load main class com.salesforce.dataloader.process.FindJavaRunner" along with something about setting the JAVA_HOME environment variable before running process.bat.

I got that JAVA_HOME error with the dataloader-42.0.0-java-home.exe error as well, but setting the JAVA_HOME environment variable only makes process.bat always give "The system cannot find the path specified" as an error.

I'm pretty much stuck now, as running process.bat within the bin folder works perfectly fine, but I'd have to move all my files there which seems like a bad plan.

Comment: Can you confirm that the JAVA_HOME variable points to the patch where Java JRE 1.8 (***32-bit***) is installed? As you can see in the doc, this is the requiered version: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=installing_the_data_loader.htm

Comment: I have verified that it is pointing at the right JRE directory, yes. Still giving me the "The system cannot find the path specified" error.

Comment: Did you see if your process.bat file is blank or has code in it. I once found my process.bat file completely blank and uninstalling, re-installing pretty much did the job